# How come half the triangle is missing

Tags: html, css

I was looking at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) to see how to make a triangle with css. In the comments there was a question about how to give the triangle a border.

I thought I had a solution, but the results were unexpected. How come the right half of the inner triangle is missing.

```css
#outer {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
#inner {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  top: -6px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid green;
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If I change the inner triangle to have `display: block` or `display: inline-block`, the right half exists, but it's gone when then inner triangle has `display: inline` and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange, it works on Firefox and IE.

You can make it work on Chrome with

```css
#inner::after {
  content: '\200B';
}
```

```css
#outer {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
#inner {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  top: -6px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid green;
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
#inner::after {
  content: '\200B';
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome. I'm interested in understanding why you would even think to add some content in `::after`?

Comment: @CallMeNorm I saw there was no problem if the element ended with a non-space character. So I inserted a zero-width character with CSS.